# single photo 2d to 3d reconstruction in ubuntu repository

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, official-repositories

A while ago, I was doing "man -a --regex 'something_don-t_remember'" and one of the programs, that came up was a cli program for a complete reconstruction of 3D scene from a single photo.
In that program's manual, it said, that it's an experimental program for 3D reconstruction from a single photo, although, in the manual, it also said, that multiple photos could also be used.
The manual was huge with many parameters, so I wanted to return to that program later.
Now, a couple of years has passed and I've forgot it's name and tried to do man -a --regex with various search phrases, but didn't find that program again.
I am sure, that this program is a part of some Ubuntu's standard repository, not from launchpad or some other 3rd party repo, because, at the time, I did it, I didn't connect any 3rd party rpos, than.
Maybe, somebody knows, what is the name of the package/program and it's not png23d, because png23d has a few parameters, but that program's man had so much documentation, like in qemu, for example.

Comment: Try to look through http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphics/ and see if anything sticks out? `png23d` is in this list.

Comment: I don't know, I guess, after looking @ suggested link, the closest thing, that I've found is 'mve'. Can anybody suggest, if 'mve' is what I am thinking, it does.

Comment: Nobody can read your mind though. Your best bet is to install it and see if it is what you saw.

Comment: You don't need to read my mind. I've described already everything in question text and title. Why do I have to repeat in comment?

Comment: Good luck finding it then.

Comment: I give up, I looked through all packages in the list.  Don't see anything familiar.  Just hope, will stumble upon it, sometimes, while manning again with some lucky search string.